# Lebesgue-measure of a cone

Tags: measure-theory

We are looking at $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and the Lebesgue-measure $\lambda_d$. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a measurable set  with $\lambda_d(A) < \infty$. For $c \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ let $cA:= \{ca\space| \space a \in A \}$. I already showed that $\lambda_d(cA)=c^d \lambda_d(A)$.

For a subset of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ and $h >0$ define a cone  $C(A,h) \subset  \mathbb{R}^d$. $h$ is the height and $A$ is the union of all connecting lines of points in $A \times \{0\}$ to the point $(0,h) \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^d$. For $c \in [0,h]$ let $E_c=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d-1} \space | \space (x,c) \in C(A,h) \}$.

Show that $E_c=(1- c/h)A$.